# Why set insert the item in ordered?

Tags: java, collections, set

Actually Set is not an ordered one. I just create the set and insert the numbers `5,2,10`.
Wen it is printed in the console, it prints as `2,5,10`.

Why since set is not ordered?

Comment: That is exactly why its not ordered. it doesn't keep the order that you insert into. For simplicity and efficiency it sort stuff for you. Its a good thing

Comment: What implementation of Set did you use? If it is HashSet then maybe add 120 to it and you will see that it is not actually ordered `[2, 5, 120, 10]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because this speeds up queries for whether a certain element is part of the set.

The difference is that this behavior is not guaranteed. It may be beneficial to keep small sets ordered for fast lookup, but switch to a hash based implementation once a certain number of elements has been reached, at which point elements would suddenly be sorted by hash value.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is an `interface` while it has several implementations. `HashSet` is not guaranteed your insertion order(not ordered). `LinkedHashSet` preserve insertion order and `TreeSet` give you a sorted `set`(sorted set).

Then you insert `5,2,10` to `HashSet` you can't guaranteed the same order.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is just an interface, assuming that you are talking about `HashSet` (because it's where this happens), it doesn't keep them sorted. For example:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
set.add(16);
System.out.println(set);
```

*Output*

```
[16, 1]
```

This is because an `HashSet` uses the `hashcode` function to compute the index where the item will be stored in an array-like structure. This way, since the `hashcode` never changes, it can extract the element from the correct index computing again the `hashcode` and checking the cell at that index.

The `hashcode` function converts *most* classes to an integer:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(1).hashCode());      # 1
System.out.println(new Integer(1000).hashCode());   # 1000
System.out.println("Hello".hashCode());             # 69609650
```

Each class can define its own way to compute the *hashcode* and `Integer` returns itself.
As you can see numbers get big soon, and we don't want to have an array with *1000* cells just to save the two integers.
To avoid the problem we can create an array with `n` elements and then use the remainder of the *hashcode* divided by `n` as the *index*.

For example if we want to find the index for `1000` in an array of *16* elements:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(1000).hashCode() % 16);   # 8
```

So our dictionary will know that the integer `1000` is at index *8*. That's how `HashSet` is implemented.

So, why `[16, 1]` is not ordered? That's because `HashSet` are created with *16* elements as capacity at the beginning (when not differently specified), and grow as needed (more on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet())).

Let's compute the index to store the data having `key = 2` and `key = 9` in a dictionary with `n = 8`:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(1).hashCode() % 16);   # 1
System.out.println(new Integer(16).hashCode() % 16);  # 0
```

This means that the *array* that contains the dictionary data will be:

```
| index | value |
|-------|-------|
|   0   |  16   |
|   1   |   1   |
|   2   |       |
|   3   |       |
|   4   |       |
|   5   |       |
|   6   |       |
|   7   |       |
|   8   |       |
|   9   |       |
|  10   |       |
|  11   |       |
|  12   |       |
|  13   |       |
|  14   |       |
|  15   |       |
```

Iterating over it, the order will be the one presented in this representation, so `16` will be before `1`.

Comment: I guess the author is talking about `Interface Set<E>`

Comment: Mapping from a hashCode to a table position is not always that easy and in fact differs across the implementations. So documenting it to that detail leads to the wrong impression that the actual position was predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Set is the Interface. It only indicates avoid duplicate entity of the collection.

[HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) internally uses Hashmap. Normally hashmap uses hashcode. So It wont return in ordered way. If you want insertion order you will use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score -1):

`Set` is just an interface. Ordering will depend on implementation. For example `TreeSet` is an ordered implementation of `Set`.

Comment: `TreeSet` is not ordered it it sorted. You can edit your answer or delete.

Comment: The Javadoc says `The elements are ordered using their natural ordering`.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of natural ordering? it is the same meaning of sorted. when you insert `1,5,4` to `TreeSet` it will give you `1,4,5` Ordered means whether collection preserve the insertion order or not.

Comment: Ordered just means ordered. If it is the insertion order, natural order or whatever else depends on the implementation.